# unknown error: cannot determine loading status from disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer error with Selenium Java scripts on jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver

I am following a tutorial on how to create and run java selenium scripts both **locally** and **on a jenkins server** using **maven** and **eclipse**.

My script is pretty basic and runs fine locally when ran through eclipse via maven and TestNG.
When i run them on Jenkins the build takes between 3 minutes to 15 minutes and then it fails with a timeout rendering issue usually.

My script when ran locally only takes about 2 minutes at most.

Has anyone had this issue before?
I am not sure why they timeout.

## Error from Jenkins

```
unknown error: cannot determine loading status from disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer   (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.108)   (Driver info: chromedriver=78.0.3904.105 (60e2d8774a8151efa6a00b1f358371b1e0e07ee2-refs/branch-heads/3904@{#877}),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.6 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 7.77 seconds Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8e7ca8e37638dc3091b2440b90a1d8686f', time: '2015-02-27 09:10:26' System info: host: 'Eamons-MBP.hitronhub.home', ip: '192.168.0.23', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.6', java.version: '1.8.0_101' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver Capabilities [{mobileEmulationEnabled=false, timeouts={implicit=0, pageLoad=300000, script=30000}, hasTouchScreen=false, platform=MAC, acceptSslCerts=false, goog:chromeOptions={debuggerAddress=localhost:60317}, acceptInsecureCerts=false, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, setWindowRect=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=ignore, applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=78.0.3904.105 (60e2d8774a8151efa6a00b1f358371b1e0e07ee2-refs/branch-heads/3904@{#877}), userDataDir=/var/folders/q3/3hrl35417q113_mhrglxf5cw00008b/T/.com.google.Chrome.Opshna}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, strictFileInteractability=false, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=78.0.3904.108, browserConnectionEnabled=false, proxy={}, nativeEvents=true, locationContextEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}] Session ID: 7261e3005842ddc3d850504ba249d136
Stacktrace
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.108)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=78.0.3904.105 (60e2d8774a8151efa6a00b1f358371b1e0e07ee2-refs/branch-heads/3904@{#877}),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.6 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 7.77 seconds
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8e7ca8e37638dc3091b2440b90a1d8686f', time: '2015-02-27 09:10:26'
System info: host: 'Eamons-MBP.hitronhub.home', ip: '192.168.0.23', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.6', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{mobileEmulationEnabled=false, timeouts={implicit=0, pageLoad=300000, script=30000}, hasTouchScreen=false, platform=MAC, acceptSslCerts=false, goog:chromeOptions={debuggerAddress=localhost:60317}, acceptInsecureCerts=false, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, setWindowRect=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=ignore, applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=78.0.3904.105 (60e2d8774a8151efa6a00b1f358371b1e0e07ee2-refs/branch-heads/3904@{#877}), userDataDir=/var/folders/q3/3hrl35417q113_mhrglxf5cw00008b/T/.com.google.Chrome.Opshna}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, strictFileInteractability=false, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=78.0.3904.108, browserConnectionEnabled=false, proxy={}, nativeEvents=true, locationContextEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 7261e3005842ddc3d850504ba249d136
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:304)
    at Eamon.EamonTest.doSomething(EamonTest.java:37)
Standard Error
Starting ChromeDriver 78.0.3904.105 (60e2d8774a8151efa6a00b1f358371b1e0e07ee2-refs/branch-heads/3904@{#877}) on port 40247
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
[1574697681.040][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
[1574697692.398][SEVERE]: Unable to receive message from renderer
```

## My Script

```
   @Test
   public class NewTest {

        @Test
         public void doSomething() {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/Eamon/Desktop/chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;


        String baseUrl = "http://www.nfl.com/probowl/ballot";
        //"http://www.nfl.com/probowl/ballot";
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        WebElement html = driver.findElement(By.tagName("html"));
        html.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.ADD));
        html.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "25"));

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,500)");
        driver.findElement(By.id("1015811_13_1_10")).click();

        js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,1000)");
        driver.findElement(By.id("ballot-submit")).click();

        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
         }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
unknown error: cannot determine loading status from disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer   (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.108)   (Driver info: chromedriver=78.0.3904.105 (60e2d8774a8151efa6a00b1f358371b1e0e07ee2-refs/branch-heads/3904@{#877}),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.6 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 7.77 seconds Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8e7ca8e37638dc3091b2440b90a1d8686f', time: '2015-02-27 09:10:26' System info: host: 'Eamons-MBP.hitronhub.home', ip: '192.168.0.23', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.6', java.version: '1.8.0_101' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver Capabilities [{mobileEmulationEnabled=false, timeouts={implicit=0, pageLoad=300000, script=30000}, hasTouchScreen=false, platform=MAC, acceptSslCerts=false, goog:chromeOptions={debuggerAddress=localhost:60317}, acceptInsecureCerts=false, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, setWindowRect=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=ignore, applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=78.0.3904.105 (60e2d8774a8151efa6a00b1f358371b1e0e07ee2-refs/branch-heads/3904@{#877}), userDataDir=/var/folders/q3/3hrl35417q113_mhrglxf5cw00008b/T/.com.google.Chrome.Opshna}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, strictFileInteractability=false, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=78.0.3904.108, browserConnectionEnabled=false, proxy={}, nativeEvents=true, locationContextEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}] Session ID: 7261e3005842ddc3d850504ba249d136
Stacktrace
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.108)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=78.0.3904.105 (60e2d8774a8151efa6a00b1f358371b1e0e07ee2-refs/branch-heads/3904@{#877}),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.6 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 7.77 seconds
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8e7ca8e37638dc3091b2440b90a1d8686f', time: '2015-02-27 09:10:26'
System info: host: 'Eamons-MBP.hitronhub.home', ip: '192.168.0.23', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.6', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
.
Standard Error
Starting ChromeDriver 78.0.3904.105 (60e2d8774a8151efa6a00b1f358371b1e0e07ee2-refs/branch-heads/3904@{#877}) on port 40247
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
[1574697681.040][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
[1574697692.398][SEVERE]: Unable to receive message from renderer
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=78.0.3904.105*
- You are using *chrome=78.0.3904.108*
- Your *Selenium Client* version is **2.45.0** of *2015-02-27 09:10:26* which is **ancient** and almost **5** years older.
- Your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_101** which is pretty ancient.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *JDK v8u101* , *Selenium Client v2.45.0* , *ChromeDriver v78.0* and the *Chrome Browser v78.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *JDK* is upgraded to  current levels [JDK 8u222](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.

Comment: Hi , i have updated JDK to latest version, selenium to latest version, cleaned and rebuilt my project but i still get the same error about time outs. The tiny difference in chrome and chromer driver surely cant be the reason i am getting this error?